# Firebase's set() not working inside onAuthStateChanged()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing my first "big" web app with ReactJS using Firebase as my DB. Everything was going well until I came across with this issue.

I'm trying to save the user info when they log in into the app with Facebook or Twitter, I'm using the methods provided by Firebase like this:

```
authenticate(option){        

    let provider;

    switch (option) {
        case 'facebook':
            provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();                
            break;
        case 'twitter':
            provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
            break;
        default:
            provider = 'no-provider'
            break;
    }

    if(provider !== 'no-provider'){
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
            console.log("Login with " + provider + " ok!");
            console.log(result);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error: there was an error trying to login.");
        });
    }
}
```

But when I try to save the user into the DB once they've logged in, nothing happens.

This is what I have on **App.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    base.auth().onAuthStateChanged((loggedUser) => {
        if (loggedUser) {
            this.setState({
                userName: loggedUser.displayName,
                userPhoto: loggedUser.photoURL,
                userUID: loggedUser.uid
            });

            base.database().ref('users/' + loggedUser.uid).on('value',
                (user) => {
                    if (user.val() !== null) {
                        if (user.val().votedAlbums !== undefined) {
                            this.setState({
                                votedAlbums: user.val().votedAlbums
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log(loggedUser.uid);
                        let userInfo = {
                            lastActivityTime: new Date()
                        }
                        base.database().ref('users/' + loggedUser.uid).set(userInfo).then((ref) =>{
                            console.log(ref); // this logs 'undefined'
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    }
                },
                (err) => {
                    this.props.history.push('/error');
                }
            );


        }
    });
}
```

I tried saving the user on another function and it works, both `update()` and `set()`. But when I call `set()` inside `onAuthStateChanged()` it doesn't.

My DB rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that `loggedUser.uid` is not empty before the set method with `console.log(loggedUser.uid)`

Comment: @bennygenel Yes, is not empty. I have only tested with one user. I did a `console.log(loggedUser);` and the uid was there.

Comment: Where did you log? inside the callback of `on('value', ....)`?

Comment: No, before that. After setting `this.setState()`

Comment: please check it inside after the else statement. because `on(..)` method is async it might be loosing its value.

Comment: I check it with the `console.log(loggedUser.uid);` inside the `on(...)` and it worked.

Comment: Worked you mean it logged the id?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The id was logged.

Comment: Does it throw any errors? can you add a catch method to set please

Comment: Maybe, and this is just a guess, it has to do with my DB rules?

Comment: yes I believe so. but user should be authorized since you get the loggedUser.

Comment: Just added the DB rules to the question

Comment: Rules are looking fine. Can you add the catch to set method please.

Comment: I edited the code. Don't know if it is correct

Comment: Yes its correct. Does it log any errors?

Comment: No, no errors...

Comment: I have 2 more theories. Other than those I don't know how can you solve this. It should work. First I suggest you change your write rule to true and see if its because of the rules. Secondly try to set some value manually like `set({foo: 'bar'})` to see if the problem is related to `new Date` that it shouldn't be.

Comment: @bennygenel I tried your suggestions. I change the rules, both to `true` and it didn't work. Then I change the `new Date()` to a simple string and it worked!!! Thank you so much. I'm not sure how to post the correct answer to my question. I'll write an answer and give you credit for it. If you can explain why this happened will be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bennygenel suggested, I changed the value of `lastActivityTime` to a simple string like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
        base.auth().onAuthStateChanged((loggedUser) => {
            if (loggedUser) {
                this.setState({
                    userName: loggedUser.displayName,
                    userPhoto: loggedUser.photoURL,
                    userUID: loggedUser.uid
                });

                base.database().ref('users/' + loggedUser.uid).once('value',
                    (user) => {
                        if (user.val() !== null) {
                            if (user.val().votedAlbums !== undefined) {
                                this.setState({
                                    votedAlbums: user.val().votedAlbums
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log(loggedUser.uid);

                            let userInfo = {
                                lastActivityTime: "whatever" // replaced new Date() with "whatever"
                            }
                            base.database().ref('users/' + loggedUser.uid).set(userInfo).then((ref) =>{
                                console.log(ref);
                            }).catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        this.props.history.push('/error');
                    }
                );


            }
        });
    }
```

And now when the user logs in its added to the DB. I also changed the `on()` method with `once()` because it was adding the user even if I deleted directly from the Firebase console.

Now to add the date to `lastActivityItem` I only have to add the `toString()` method to the generated date like this:

```
let d = new Date()

let userInfo = {
    lastActivityTime: d.toString()
}
```

If someone knows why this happened, please share.

Thank you @bennygenel !!!

Comment: It because `new Date` is a date object and you need to stringify it. You can use some toString method or getTime method